# Problems running jprofiler on iSeries / AS400

Tags: java, profiling, ibm-midrange, jprofiler

I'm trying to get JProfiler 7.X running on AS400. I adjusted the setenv.sh according to the instructions mentioned in this blog post (https://blog.oio.de/2013/06/03/how-to-connect-jprofiler-with-tomcat-7-0-27-running-on-ibm-j9-64-bit-jdklinux/).

As soon as i run startup.sh the JVM crashes complaining about non existing directory or file. It seems that the linux-x64 modules aren't compatible with OS400 environment.

Do you have any experience running jprofiler on OS400?

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you are using the linux version.  Have you tried the 64-bit AIX version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JProfiler does not have any native libraries for AS400, it's not possible to use it to profile on that platform.